# No My Sites link after installing Multisite

Tags: multisite

I have just setup a fresh Centos server onto which I have installed the latest version of Wordpress. I then enabled multisite and went through and changed my .htaccess and wp-config as shown. I  then logged out and back in again but there is not any My Sites menu at the top on the dashboard.

I have tried clearing my cache and on several different browser so I am pretty certain that it is a server issue.

This is the relevant part from wp-config:

```
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'test.site.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

And this is the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Can anyone see any issues or suggest where I might look next?

Comment: Do you have any sites to list? Or just the root site? What's listed in the sites section of the network admin? ( not all sites on a network are listed in my sites, they're specific to you the user, not the install )

Comment: @TomJNowell that's my point - there isn't a sites section. It's as if MU hasn't been enabled. But if I try to create a new one it says "An existing WordPress network was detected." So something is not right somewhere.

Comment: Then you are clearly looking at the admin interface, *not* the network admin interface. go to /wp-admin/network and tell us what you see ( you will need super admin privilleges to do so ). Be sure that you followed all the instructions in the correct order. Simply copy pasting a full set of multisite defines into a wp-config.php of a single site will not give you a multisite, and misses out important steps inbetween

Comment: @TomJNowell aware of all that as I have done an install successfully a number of times. Anyway, I deleted the install and started again and it has worked this time - thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2):

When you edit wp-config.php the second time - when the installer tells you to update your wp-config.php file with a bunch of multisite-related includes - at this point remove the definition for WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE.

REMOVE this line:
`define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);`

based on your example above, you'd be left with:

```
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'test.site.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Once I did that, I logged back in and suddenly the "My sites" menu appeared!